# How to query site data in hugo using where

Tags: hugo

In a hugo template how can I do a lookup on `.Site.Data`. Assuming I have a data structure like this:

```json
{
    "my-blog-post": {
        "Version": 21,
        "Revision": 0,
        "Code": "my-blog-post",
        "Name": "My Blog Post",
        "Parent": "the-parent-post"
    },
    "another-post": {
        "Version": 21,
        "Revision": 0,
        "Code": "another-post",
        "Name": "Another Post",
        "Parent": "the-parent-post"
    }

}
```

Inside the detail page for a blog post, I would like to get the list of all the posts that have the current post as the parent. Basically I would like to query posts that have "the-parent-post" as the value of Parent field.
I can achieve this using range but I need to get them using where.
I experimented with expressions like this but no joy.

```golang
{{$child_posts := where (where .Site.Data "Section" "blog") "Parent" "the-parent-post" }}
```

I can do this:

```golang
{{$posts := where $site.Pages "Section" "blog"}}
{{ range sort $posts "Name" "asc" }}
    {{ $post := . }}
    {{if eq $post.parent $currentPage.Code}}
          ...Do something...
    {{end}}
{{end}}
```

But it is not ideal and not what I need.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to range through a map of maps. You need an array of maps.

https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/filtering-data-in-json-using-where/35287/2